# CSP error for bootstrap image in navbar hamburger

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I just added content security policy to my Django site. I have everything working correctly except these two errors for images that I had no idea what they were
[image]

I spent a bunch of time trying to figure it out until I noticed that the icon on the bootstrap hamburger menu was gone

[image]

In the CSS I found this telling me that this must be the image in the navbar causing this error.

[image]

I found a few workarounds online but they presented security vulnerabilities and i would like to do it properly How can I go about solving this issue.

CSP

```
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'", 
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    ...
    
    )
  
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'self'",
    "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/",
    ...

    )
```

Answer (score 1):

From the code snippets, it looks like you are using https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html package to handle the setting of the CSP directives and that is a great choice for the Django projects.

The most secure scenario would be if you allow loading of the content from the same domain and strictly forbid any other resources, it isn't practical though. A good enough strategy would be if you allow 'self' and only explicit paths like `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css`. Values like `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/`, `cdn.jsdelivr.net` or `https:` could raise concerns as they will be allowing a wide range of resources.

In your case `data:` might be required for the `img-src` directive or `default-src` which will act as a fallback in case you don't have an explicit `img-src` directive value.

https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/ could give you more security recommendations for your current CSP configuration and specific domains that you are using.

Comment: Allow `data:` worked. However I could download the image and store it locally and link it up via css/html. Would this be a better approach?

Comment: Yes, technically that will be a better option rather than allowing `:data`.